# How to automatically force delete pods stuck in 'Terminating' after node failure?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment that deploys a single pod with a persistent volume claim. If I switch off the node it is running on, after a while k8s terminates the pod and tries to spin it up elsewhere. However the new pod cannot attach the volume (Multi-Attach error for volume "pvc-...").

I can manually delete the old 'Terminating' pod with `kubectl delete pod <PODNAME> --grace-period=0 --force` and then things recover.

Is there a way to get Kubernetes to force delete the 'Terminating' pods after a timeout or something? Tx.

Comment: The easiest solution I can think for this is to have the PVC in ReadWriteMany. Then force-terminating the Pod wouldn't be necessary anymore. But, of course, you need to have something that can give you ReadWriteMany persistent volumes or it will not work. Is this an ok solution or you want to use ReadWriteOnce volumes?

Comment: I could do that but am worried about what happens if the node is just network partitioned and comes back. Then the "old" pod might end up writing to the volume. Better if it no longer has it. I am using rook-ceph.

Comment: Well, force delete a Pod has the same effect if the node is network partitioned.. it will not stop the container from running on the node which is cut out of the network.. until the node reconnects and notice that things has changed from the control-plane prospective. So it can happen in the other way as well, I think. It depends on ceph if the volume is still mounted on the node which was partitioned.. if it is automatically attached again or not.. and so on

Comment: Hmm will have to try test that. Ceph loses its quorum quite quickly so hopefully that also applies to the node on the wrong side of the partition and it stops using the volume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/force-delete-stateful-set-pod/):

> A Pod is not deleted automatically when a node is unreachable. The
> Pods running on an unreachable Node enter the 'Terminating' or
> 'Unknown' state after a timeout. Pods may also enter these states when
> the user attempts graceful deletion of a Pod on an unreachable Node.
> The only ways in which a Pod in such a state can be removed from the
> apiserver are as follows:
>
> - The Node object is deleted (either by you, or by the Node Controller).
> - The kubelet on the unresponsive Node starts responding, kills the Pod and removes the entry from the apiserver.
> - Force deletion of the Pod by the user.

So I assume you are not deleting nor draining the node that is being shut down.
In general I'd advice to ensure any broken nodes are deleted from the node list and that should make `Terminating` pods to be deleted by controller manager.
Node deletion normally happens automatically, at least on kubernetes clusters running on the main cloud providers, but if that's not happening for you than you need a way to remove nodes that are not healthy.

Comment: This is a bare metal deployment and the dead node is still there 3 hours later so guess it is staying. I will play more with this tm. Tx.

Comment: I supposed I could write a little script to force delete 'Terminating' pods with a given label.

Comment: I deleted the NotReady node `kubectl delete node ..` and the Terminating pod that was on it is still stuck for a few minutes. However after that it disappeared. The new one still fails to start (Unable to attach or mount volumes:..) but I think thats because Ceph is unhappy which is a different problem.

Comment: Update: Rook-ceph sorted itself out after a few minutes and the volume mounted and my service is up. So removing the dead node works. Now I need to find out how to do that automatically after a timeout.

Comment: On a related note I restarted the dead node and it rejoined the cluster seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Recreate` in `.spec.strategy.type` of your Deployment. This tell Kubernetes to delete the old pods before creating new ones.

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#strategy

Comment: I do have that and it works when I restart the deployment etc.. In this case the old pod just gets stuck in 'Terminating'.